# How to hold the old points in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, plot, points, graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to plot points on rviz graph. I was successful in doing that however I could not plot the new points without loosing the old points. I want the graph to populate with newer values every-time (Real tine sensor values plotting). How can I do that ? Also is there any method of plotting except for rviz. I don't want to manually type rosrun rviz rivz all the time.
Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194637/how-to-hold-the-old-points-in-rviz/) by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-10-10**:
did you try `marker.action = visualization_msgs::Marker::ADD`

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-10-14**:
I did but didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For visualization, there's a decay time parameter for most Rviz displays. If you want to do specific aggregation logic, you'll probably need to write a node which does the aggregation logic you want and then sends out the resultant value.

There are lots of domain specific examples such as the [laser_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler)

rviz is installed into your path you can just run `rviz`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aniket](https://answers.ros.org/users/18764/aniket/) on 2014-10-14**:
thanks, helps a lot.